# Debug Toolbar Symfony internal Server Error

Tags: symfony, apache2, twig

I get an the following error if i log out me from App.

An error occurred while loading the web debug toolbar (500: Internal Server Error). Do you want to open the profiler?

I can't find anything in the error log, have anyone an idea, why this error can occur?

I find in the 1dev.log` following Error Line

**Update**

> [2014-10-31 12:50:47] request.ERROR: Uncaught PHP Exception
>   Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Exception\NotFoundHttpException: "No
>   route found for "GET //_wdt/6ce745"" at
>   /var/www/app/trunk/app/cache/dev/classes.php line 1881
>   {"exception":"[object]
>   (Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Exception\NotFoundHttpException: No
>   route found for \"GET //_wdt/6ce745\" at
>   /var/www/app/trunk/app/cache/dev/classes.php:1881,
>   Symfony\Component\Routing\Exception\ResourceNotFoundException:  at
>   /var/www/app/trunk/app/cache/dev/appDevUrlMatcher.php:506)"} []

This error occur on logout from app. The logout request redirect me on the login page.

Comment: You mentioned the logout procedure. Did you by any chance remove system firewall (one that has `_dev`, `_profiler`, etc...)?

Comment: On the production enviorment everything is ok. How can i remove this?

Comment: You cannot and, most importantly, you should not. Please see the original `security.yml` in order to restore default firewall (you don't need to remove one you've just made)

Comment: I add the orginal security yml. But i think the problem is the trailing slash after logout i get the url "/app_dev.php/" and if if remove the last slash everything is fine. But i don't know why the trailing slash exists on logout

Answer (score 2):

Yes look in your Symfony2 error logs

```
app/logs/yourenv.log
```

There you can find some more informations.

Comment: Thank you for the hint. I look in my dev.log and update my question with the log output.